# Devexpress MVC Submit button with client side validation

Tags: model-view-controller, devexpress, client, unobtrusive-validation

Is there anyway to do client side validations to work with Devexpress MVC submit button? In my scenario, the normal html submit button will work perfectly without firing the Controller action, but Devexpress button always fire the controller action, means its not actually a client side validation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
Buttonsettings.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
Buttonsettings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s ,e) { OnSubmit()}";
```